# Creating a FileInfo from a file added to the solution as a link

Tags: c#, .net, fileinfo

Is there an easy way to create a FileInfo based on a hardcoded relative path to a location added to the solution as a link? I've tried referencing the working directory but that only explicitly checks the files there. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please show your code. It's not really clear what you're trying to do or why that doesn't work. What type is the linked file and is it copied to the output directory? What is wrong with "explicitly checking the file is there" and what else do you expect it to do?

Comment: _" I've tried..."_ Always show what you've tried.